# Existing Java implementation for a map with a list of values?

Tags: java, data-structures, dictionary

A common type of datastructure I might use is a

```
   Map<String,List<MyObject>> myMap...
```

The common operation I'd do is to add an object to the list given a matching key. For example,

```
  myMap.addValueToList("Key", myObject)
```

Implementing this is not very tricky, but it is a bit ugly (for this example, assume that myObject contains the key):

```
for (MyObject myObject : myObjects) {
   List<MyObject> newList = newArrayList();
   if (myMap.contains(myObject.key)) {
     newList = myMap.get(myObject.key);
   }
   newList.add(myObject);
   myMap.put(myObject.key, newList);
}
```

I do this kind of operation more often than I'd like. Last time, I wrote my own class for this functionality, but I wonder if there isn't some kind of implementation available in one of the commonly used libraries such as apache.

Comment: You wrote your own class? I once wrote a single static method for this. Your larger code block would suffice for this, although you should create a `new ArrayList()` only when the key is not in the map, and you only need the `put` operation in this case, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Guava MultiMap will save your time.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

And here is a post explaining its usage with examples:

http://tomjefferys.blogspot.nl/2011/09/multimaps-google-guava.html

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and very simple interface. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is called a MultiMap, and there is an existing implementation of it in Apache commons: **[MultiMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/MultiMap.html)**